# How to automate the updating of AMI images in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've created an AWS AMI image in which have all my required applications installed in it.Later on I used autoscaling to create ec2 instances from the AMI image (in which I created before).
what I need to do is:
Updating the codes inside the AMI image,so the instances will use the new version.and this happens often, 
I know that I can create a new image every time, but is there anyway to automate this process? for instance, updating it directly from git, or jenkins or .... 
How can I possibility automate this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS [Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/) [Automation](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/automation/) was just announced, which can [automate AMI updating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eal9K0aGLYI&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 3):

[Packer](http://www.packer.io/) is the tool you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot,The application looks amazing.